# Вернуть ответ Accepted (202) на запрос не дожидаясь его обработки

Tags: c#, angular2, asp.net-core, rxjs, asp.net-core-2

### Задача

Мне необходимо в action контроллере:

1. Получить файл.
2. Сначала (сразу) отправить ответ с кодом 202 (Accepted), чтобы клиент не ждал окончания обработки файла.
3. Начать обработку файла.

### Мое решение

Я сделал так:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddFile(IFormFile file)
{    
    Task.Run(() => { fileService.Process(file.OpenReadStream()); });

    return Accepted();
}
```

Но это не сработало: ответ возвращается, но обработка не происходит. И как я понял, фоновый поток, создаваемый `Task.Run()`, сразу умирает как только завершается главный поток.

### Вопрос

Как быть в таком случаи? До этого реализовывать подобную бизнес-логику мне не приходилось и быть может даже правильнее пытаться на стороне клиента (там у меня `Angular 6`) это как-то реализовывать?

Comment: Как вариант попробуйте инициировать новый запрос в AddFile к другому action, и потом возвращать 202.

Comment: @Anamnian, о таком варианте исполнения я тоже думал, но мне почему-то кажется, что это больше хард-код и как-то по-другому должно все это реализовываться.

Comment: Ответ дан на [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25274096/how-to-answer-a-request-but-continue-processing-code-in-webapi).

Comment: `Task.Run()` не умирает, когда завершается обработка запроса. Скорее всего у вас валится ексепшн в `file.OpenReadStream()` в момент утилизации ресурсов запроса. Попробуйте сперва считать файл и уже потом запускать фоновую обработку и возвращать `202`.